# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

Ive currently created an app that is meant to mimic fiverr, im currently trying to create a registration form for users who are currently active on the site, as freelancers, this is being handled using the Devise gem on ruby. Im having a problem when posting my form however, as it keeps coming back saying it couldnt find the user without an ID.
Here below is my form

````
```ruby
<%= form_with model: @user do |form|%>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name"%>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name"%>
    <%= form.text_field :bio, placeholder: "Bio"%>
    <%= form.number_field :cost, placeholder: "Cost per hour in $'s"%>
    <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>```
````

and then here is my pages_controller

````
```ruby
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def registration_form
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def register_freelancer
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(seller_params)
    current_user.freelancer!
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) 
  end

  private
  def seller_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :cost)
  end
end
```
````

Here is my routes

````
```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users

  resources :pages

  get '/home' => 'pages#home'

  get '/registration_form' => 'pages#registration_form'
  post 'registration_form' => 'pages#register_freelancer'

end
````

```
and here is a screenshot of my table
[table][4]
 Im using ruby on rails 7.0, and a postgres database, please can someone advise me what step im missing out on to update these database?
 
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4cnn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5zDc.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrxc8.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwxyw.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to find the user in `registration_form` action, I think this should work

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :registration_form]

  def home; end

  def registration_form; end

  def edit; end

  def register_freelancer
    @user.update(seller_params)
    current_user.freelancer!
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) 
  end

  private
  
  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end

  def seller_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :cost)
  end
end
```

Then update the form to this

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, url: registration_form_path), method: :post do |form|%>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name"%>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name"%>
    <%= form.text_field :bio, placeholder: "Bio"%>
    <%= form.number_field :cost, placeholder: "Cost per hour in $'s"%>
    <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives me an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID)

Comment: I updated the answer, added one more before_action and updated the set_user metod. Could you plz check now? @LukeCzoboriek

Comment: So that caused a different error this time, it seems to have produced an error before the form was even done, its saying 'undefined method 'user_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000022268>

On line 23 of the registration_form, where it says <%= form_with...

Comment: can you share screenshot of the code and error now?

Comment: Of course
https://ibb.co/tJ2xtJZ
https://ibb.co/WBQv1pG
https://ibb.co/L6pk7Wg

Comment: Updated the answer again, plz check @LukeCzoboriek

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not correct approach how you are trying to update user fields, but here is what you should do to make it works:

Since you have defined these two routes:

```rb
get 'registration_form' => 'pages#registration_form'
post 'registration_form' => 'pages#register_freelancer'
```

These routes don't suppose to have user ID in the URL as a fragment so that you need to pass it explicit:

```rb
# add ?id=1 to your route
http://localhost:3000/registration_form?id=1
```

And then change your action and form:

```rb
def registration_form
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

```rb
<%= form_with model: @user, url: registration_form_path(id: @user.id), method: :post do |form|%>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name"%>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name"%>
  <%= form.text_field :bio, placeholder: "Bio"%>
  <%= form.number_field :cost, placeholder: "Cost per hour in $'s"%>
  <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>
```

**Update**:

So that your routes support user ID as a fragment you need to change your routes:

```rb
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'registration_form' => 'pages#registration_form'
    post 'registration_form' => 'pages#register_freelancer'
  end
end
```

After this change your will have these URLs:

```rb
registration_form_user GET    /users/:id/registration_form(.:format)
registration_form_user POST   /users/:id/registration_form(.:format)
```

So you need to change your paths from `registration_form` to `registration_form_user(USER_INSTANSE)`. You need to replace `USER_INSTANSE` to user instance you want to fill out registration_form

And change your form

```rb
<%= form_with model: @user, url: registration_form_user_path(@user), method: :post do |form|%>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name"%>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name"%>
  <%= form.text_field :bio, placeholder: "Bio"%>
  <%= form.number_field :cost, placeholder: "Cost per hour in $'s"%>
  <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: This unfortunately also does not work i get a 
NoMethodError in Pages#registration_form 
Showing /home/luke/newassignment/freelancer_assignment/app/views/pages/registration_form.html.erb where line #23 raised: 
<%= form_with model: @user, url: registration_form_path(id: @user.id), method: :post do |form|%>

Comment: What code do you have at line 23 in `app/views/pages/registration_form.html.erb`?

Comment: <%= form_with model: @user, url: registration_form_path(id: @user.id), method: :post do |form|%>

Comment: Did you add  this code `@user = User.find(params[:id])`  to the `registration_form ` action? and this `?id=1` to your URL in browser?

Comment: Yeh i did, didnt seem to save, its now erroring out on that code there in registration_form action, saying the couldnt find user without an id

Comment: Replace `?id=1` with an ID that exists in your database. Run this code `User.limit(5).ids` in console and write me returned result here

Comment: okay that worked adding the ?id=1 thing, i didnt realise what you meant with that, so how do i fix this whole issue then without manually adding the id to the url bar

Comment: You have to change your routes so that they support `id` params as segment. But it's another question)

Comment: Okay, im really sorry im still relatively new to this tech stack, could you please explain what i need to put in this routes part?

Comment: Okay thanks for trying, its still throwing errors about the id, ive also got a weird problem now where i cant logout and destroy the session. I think im guna call it quits and go back to basics at this point, when your stuck on a problem for 6 hours of the day, i think its best